# selenium webdriver in Internet Explorer throwing an error even after done all required setting

Tags: selenium

```
public class FirstTest {    WebDriver driver;   @Test   public void test()  {   System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver","C:\\Users\\Priyanka\\Documents\\datadriver\\IEDriverServer.exe");     driver=new InternetExplorerDriver(); //driver=new FirefoxDriver(); driver.manage().window().maximize(); driver.get("http://gmail.com"); driver.findElement(By.id("userid")).sendKeys("Abc@gmail.coms"); driver.findElement(By.id("pwd")).sendKeys("abc@167"); driver.findElement(By.name("Submit")).click(); } }
```

This is my code.It will open the given URL but thows an error when trying to find webelement  Error message:

> FAILED: test org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchWindowException: Unable to find
>   element on closed window (WARNING: The server did not provide any
>   stacktrace information) Command duration or timeout: 28 milliseconds
>   Build info: version: '2.48.2', revision: '41bccdd', time: '2015-10-09
>   19:55:52' System info: host: 'Priyanka-PC', ip: '100.74.201.94',
>   os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1',
>   java.version: '1.7.0_79' *** Element info: {Using=id, value=userid}
>   Session ID: fc075a9b-5a50-42fa-ba96-ce2258254d4a Driver info:
>   org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver Capabilities
>   [{platform=WINDOWS, javascriptEnabled=true, elementScrollBehavior=0,
>   ignoreZoomSetting=false, enablePersistentHover=true,
>   ie.ensureCleanSession=false, browserName=internet explorer,
>   enableElementCacheCleanup=true, unexpectedAlertBehaviour=dismiss,
>   version=-1, pageLoadStrategy=normal, ie.usePerProcessProxy=false,
>   cssSelectorsEnabled=true, ignoreProtectedModeSettings=false,
>   requireWindowFocus=false, initialBrowserUrl=http://localhost:22334/,
>   handlesAlerts=true, ie.forceCreateProcessApi=false, nativeEvents=true,
>   browserAttachTimeout=0, ie.browserCommandLineSwitches=,
>   takesScreenshot=true}]    at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:206)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:158)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:647)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:353)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementById(RemoteWebDriver.java:403)
>     at org.openqa.selenium.By$ById.findElement(By.java:218)     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:345)
>     at demo.FirstTest.test(FirstTest.java:20)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)     at
>   org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:86)
>     at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:643)   at
>   org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:820)    at
>   org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1128)  at
>   org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:129)
>     at
>   org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:112)
>     at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:782)    at
>   org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:632)    at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:366)  at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:361)  at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:319)   at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:268)  at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)  at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)   at
>   org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1246)     at
>   org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1171)  at
>   org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1066)   at
>   org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.run(RemoteTestNG.java:113)     at
>   org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:206)  at
>   org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:177)

I have done below settings:

1. Set Security zone
2. Made entry in Registry file
3. Set environment variable
4. Set default zoom size to 100 Please guide what should i do.

This code is working fine in firefox

Answer (score 0):

Try this.
Enable protected mode for all zones in IE browser. It should be checked for all zones.
It worked for me.